# Нужна запятая в данном предложении или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Мы ужинаем дома(,) в семейном кругу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Мы ужинаем дОма, в семейном кругУ.***

Здесь обособляется обстоятельство со значением пояснения (как именно?).

Вариант с неоднородными обстоятельствами (без запятой) лучше использовать в предложениях другой структуры, например: *Мы ужинаем дома в семейном кругУ, а потом все вместе идем на прогУлку.*